¿Por qué cuando intento hacer un fallo en un xpath, no me genera report de cucumber?
Estoy intentando generar los report de cucumber. Actualmente me está funcionando bien, solo se la prueba sale PASSED. Cuando intento hacer que la prueba falle en un element, es decir, en un xpath, me muestra un fallo de NoSuchElementException y no me genera report de cucumber, solo del testing.
Había creado varias clases de customElement: os lo paso por aquí por si el problema es ese, porque no tiene sentido que la prueba, si es PASSED, sí genere report y cuando la prueba falla, no genere report.
Clase customElementLocator
public class CustomElementLocator implements ElementLocator {
    private final SearchContext searchContext;
    private final By byLocator;

    public CustomElementLocator(SearchContext searchContext, By byLocator) {
        this.searchContext = searchContext;
        this.byLocator = byLocator;
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement() {
        return searchContext.findElement(byLocator);
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements() {
        return searchContext.findElements(byLocator);
    }
}

Clase customPropertyElementLocatorFactory
public CustomPropertyElementLocatorFactory(SearchContext searchContext,String language) {

private Properties loadProperties(String language) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
         fileName = String.format(FILE_PATTERN, language);

        String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/java" + fileName;
        System.out.println("directory "+directory);
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(directory);
        props.load(file);
        languagePropertiesMap.put(language, props);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se pudo cargar el archivo de propiedades para el idioma: " + language, e);
    }
    return props;
}

Todo esto es para que me recoja bien los xpath dentro de un properties, llamando al método de Custom. El problema creo que es que cuando falla un xpath, no me genera report de cucumber. No sé si esto tiene que ver.

La solución fue añadir al POM:
<configuration>
...
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
<plugin>
..
<param>**/*.json</param>


No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.
